# como encontrar un elemento de una lista, pero solo tengo una letra como referencia que esta dentro de uno de los elementos de la list para encontrarlo

Tags: python

tengo un string que lo converti en una lista

`des1 = "Este bolso de cuero de la marca: Miguel Cors tiene un precio de 199.99€. Es una oferta especial."`

`lista1=des1.split()`

y de esa lista quiero encontrar el precio que seria [199.99€.], pero solo puedo usar el simbolo del euro (€) para encontrar ese elemento, y que me muestre en la pantalla con un print el elemento que seria [199.99€.]

lo estaba haciendo con for para que analize cada elemento de mi lista pero solo conosco los metodos find y index que necesariamente tienes que poner el nombre completo del elemento de la lista que quieres buscar para encontrarlo, pero yo solo tengo el simbolo del euro(€) para encontrarlo y ese simbolo solo esta en uno de los elementos de mi lista, y de esa manera encontrarlo y que me imprima ese elemento de mi lista que tenia el simbolo del euro(€)

Comment: Supongo que no puedes usar expresiones regulares. Así que la mejor solución que se me ocurre sería usar split para separar en palabras la cadena, recorrer la lista resultante con un bucle for y averiguar si la palabra termina en ese simbolo.

Comment: Por cierto, un consejito. Cuando pones un titulo en mayuscula en internet, das la impresión de gritar, así que te recomiendo evitar hacerlo. Además, cuando te saltas los signos de puntuación, los textos se leen decorrido y son más dificiles de entender. Pero por lo demás, buena pregunta!

Comment: @Christian por qué `lista1[i-1]`?

Comment: `precio = [x for x in lista1 if '€' in x][0]`. Ojo que esto da error si no encuentra ningún `€`.

Comment: @Fedex7501 se me pasó >_<.  En mi cabeza estaba que `€` estaba separado por un espacio.  Tu código sería el correcto

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

podrias separarlo por espacios de esta forma `lista1=des1.split(" ")`.
Te quedaria una lista en la forma

```
["Este", "bolso", "de", "cuero", "de", "la", "marca:", "Miguel", "Cors", "tiene", "un", "precio", "de", "199.99€.", "Es", "una", "oferta", "especial."]
```

Despues recorrerias cada elemento de ella buscando el simbolo y si lo encuentras guardarias la subcadena hasta el simbolo para no tomar el punto o cualquier caracter que este despues. De esta forma:

```
for i in range(len(lista1)): # recorrer por la longitud de la lista lista
    if "€" in lista1[i]: # Buscas el simbolo en cada elemento de la lista1
        valor = lista1[i][ : lista1[i].index("€")+1] # Obtener la subcadena hasta el simbolo
```

Si no sabes usar subcadenas podrias visitar [este link.](http://elclubdelautodidacta.es/wp/2011/09/python-capitulo-18-creacion-de-sublistas/)